Add file selector in Airflow Params
I have added some parameters to execute my python code like date pickers like this:
params = {
    "start_date": Param(
        f"{date.today() - timedelta(days=7)}",
        type="string",
        format="date",
        title="Start Date",
        description="Please select a start date"
    ),
    "end_date": Param(
        f"{date.today() - timedelta(days=1)}",
        type="string",
        format="date",
        title="End Date",
        description="Please select an end date"
    ),
}

But now, I'd like to be able to select manually the file to execute the code on. Is there a way to add a file selector in the parameters please ?
I could not find any proper solution in the doc
